# Result changes when update join

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a two tables which update my table to another table.

```
MasterTable tb  | EmpRecordX01132020 tb 
bankaccount     | BankAcctNo 
12345678910     | 91011121314
```

but the result on table 2 is - 1.234567e+009, both my datatypes are `varchar` but result is still the same. I want to get the original result.

```
UPDATE EmpRecordX01132020 SET 
    EmpRecordX01132020.BankAcctNo = b.bankacctno
FROM EmpRecordX01132020 a
INNER JOIN MasterTable b ON b.userid = a.UserID;
```

Comment: "but the result on table 2 is - 1.234567e+009, both my datatypes are varchar " - seems unlikely...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the alias.

```
UPDATE a
     SET BankAcctNo = b.bankacctno
FROM
    EmpRecordX01132020 a
    INNER JOIN
    MasterTable b ON b.userid = a.UserID;
```

Comment: sadly i'm still getting result of 1.60106e+009

Comment: Can we see the userids of both tables? Might be wrong but I am suspecting that join. what do you get when you run: select * FROM
    EmpRecordX01132020 a
    INNER JOIN
    MasterTable b ON b.userid = a.UserID;